# use DI to get appropriate repository to provide data to session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

When user requests to login page, LoginController is called and ninject will inject an appropriate repository to the controller (let say IAccountRepository). If the login is successful, I'll get user info from the repository and then store in Session (let say AccInfo). But if an user has a valid authorization cookie comes back to my site, the AccInfo doesn't exists in Session but I want to use it in another controller (which does not have IAccountRepository be injected in the first place). 
What should I do now? I don't want to call an concrete object (let say an AccountRepository instance) to get info from db, I still want to use DI in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe then you should not store the AccInfo in the session? Simply store the userId or somesuch, and then always inject your Repository, and use the userId to retrieve the necessary things.

If you want to minimize db access, using caching in your repository.

Comment: Thanks. so that I have to inject IAccountRepository to all of my controllers? And could you give me some details about caching in my repository

Comment: One alternative would be to use a base controller and resolve the repository there in the `OnActionExecuting` method. Then you could assign the `AccInfo` to some instance variable that is accessible from the inheriting classes. Regarding caching, it depends a bit on your requirements and setup, but have a look at the `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` class for a simple option